# Dynamic allocation of sparse matrix using uBLAS

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, ublas

I'm starting to use uBLAS for my sparse matrices. For static allocation, I do the following:

```
compressed_matrix<double> m (10,10,10);
```

However, I need dynamic allocation. [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/boost-list/9_hoDnVwlOw), they suggest the following for dynamic allocation of uBLAS matrices:

```
matrix<double> m;
m.resize(10,10);
```

But that doesn't seem to work for sparse matrices. Any ideas how to dynamically allocate sparse matrices? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory seems to be allocated dynamically anyway, so I can just do:

```
int n;
n = 10;

compressed_matrix<double> m (n,n,n);
```